# 504 error crash on openshift

Tags: tomcat, java, openshift-online-2

I have deployed a java application in openshift. I am using bronze plan. My application is a scaled application and also uses 4GB of memeory. I got an 504 error crash two or more times in a day. Please any one help me.

Comment: You got no detailed info about the problem. I doubt anyone can help you now.

Comment: There is no bug report relating this issue. I don't know why it is caused. some times it is down for up to 2 hours.Then I want to manualy restart the application

Comment: If no logs and no monitoring the run strace on it when its down

Answer (score 0):

None of the gear sizes on OpenShift support 4GB of memory.  Your application is crashing before it even gets fully started because it is running out of memory.  I am sure that is what your log files say also, you can check them with the "`rhc tail`" command.